# How to auto hide flash message when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, flash

I use ujs to send ajax request and in my **destroy.js.erb** file i have the following code :

```
$("#wrapper").prepend('<div class="flash-notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash.discard(:notice)) %></div>');
```

the line above show a flash-notice message when using ajax, what i want is to auto hide this flash message after a delay

( `$(".flash-notice").delay(600).fadeOut(300);` ) doesn't work because the message is added dynamically and not existing in the DOM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your flash message with a div in normal html template

```
<div id='notice'>
</div>
```

Then, in js template

```
$('#notice').html("<%=j msg %>").show().fadeOut(4000)
```

The `msg` method above will contain full html of `<div class='flash'>...`

Then, after fadeout, `#notice` is still in DOM but `display:none`, you can use it again anytime.

P.S. You can use a helper to process flash message so that you don't need to hard code it in template.

```
def flash_output(text, type)
  content_tag :div, class: "flash-#{type}" do
    text
  end
end
```

So the above js template can be written to

```
$('#notice').html("<%=j flash_output(msg, 'notice') %>").show().fadeOut(4000)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to have `<div class="flash-notice">` already in the dom and call something like

```
$(".flash-notice").html('<%= escape_javascript(flash.discard(:notice)) %>');
```

in your destroy.js.erb. In this way the element would already be present.

HTH

Comment: but in this case it will be disappear before adding html content to it !

Comment: I have used it many times without issue. For instance
`$('#approval_feedback').html("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice])%>");
$('#approval_feedback').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');`

Where do you put the delay call?